# Two small questions surrounding iteration of commands

Tags: macros

Two small questions here:

- Why is **Subentry3** not in `\scriptsize`?
- How to arrange **... Mainentry1** so that it will only appear at the end of the last **Subentry** (however many pairs that may be), instead of at the end of the first pair (i.e. at the end of **Subentry2**)?

## MWE

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk

\documentclass{scrreprt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%
%
\newenvironment {mainentry} {\mainentryA}{}
\def\mainentryA#1#2#3{%
   \def\subentry##1##2{%
\scriptsize ##1 \space \Huge ##2 ... #1
   }%
#1 #2 #3
}
%
%
%
\def\subentry{\def\subentryS{\def\subentryS{\endgraf}}\futurelet\next\subentryA}
\def\subentryA{\ifx\bgroup\next\expandafter\subentryB\fi}
\def\subentryB#1#2{\subentryS\subentry{#1}{#2}\futurelet\next\subentryA}
%
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{mainentry}{
Mainentry1
}{
Mainentry2
}{
Mainentry3
}

\subentry{
Subentry1
}{
Subentry2
}{
Subentry3
}{
Subentry4
}

\end{mainentry}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you *redefine* the `\subentry` macro inside the environment. Why do you blemish the outer definition of `\subentry`: there is infinitive loop of calls because `\subentryB` includes `\subentry` again? It seems that you doesn't know basic principles of TeX. It is very difficult to explain you such basics. And you are not able to formulate, what is your intend. You can try to explain this by this way: "I want to print such thing ... when I write such code ... in my source document".

Comment: @wipet I tried to use [your repetitive idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394781/macro-repeat-the-pattern-for-any-even-number-of-arguments-extra-command-bet/394921#394921), but then somehow need to put it into an encompassing environment so that I may re-use the arguments coming from one level up.

Comment: But if you need to reusing arguments then you must exactly know what you are doing. When you only blemish my code then I am not sure that you know how TeX works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One your comment of another answer here implies that you need, *maybe*, to add some data which is declared at the very start of LaTeX environment to the each end of `\subentry` usage. It means, that

```
\begin{mainentry}{AAA}{B}{}
\Subentry{C}{D}{E}{F}
\Subentry{U}{V}{W}{X}{Y}{Z}
\end{mainentry}
```

would print something like this:

```
AAA B
(sub C, sub D) (sub E, sub F) (end: AAA)
(sub U, sub V) (sub W, sub X) (sub Y, sub Z) (end: AAA)
```

But I am not sure that this is exactly your intend because you are generating many questions of this topic at this site but none of them exactly explains your intend.

You can try to experiment with this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\newenvironment {mainentry} {\mainentryA}{}
\def\mainentryA#1#2#3{%
   \def\SubentryE{\endgraf At the end of subentry collection is again (#1).}%
   \def\SubentryC##1##2{%
      Here is external paremater (#1) and second external (#2).
      And internal parameter is (##1) and second internal (##2).
   }
}
\def\Subentry{\def\SubentryS{\def\SubentryS{\endgraf}}\futurelet\next\SubentryA}
\def\SubentryA{\ifx\bgroup\next\expandafter\SubentryB\else\SubentryE\fi}
\def\SubentryB#1#2{\SubentryS\SubentryC{#1}{#2}\futurelet\next\SubentryA}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{mainentry}{A}{B}{}
\Subentry{C}{D}{E}{F}
NEXT
\Subentry{U}{V}{W}{X}{Y}{Z}
\end{mainentry}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\subentry{ Subentry1 }{ Subentry2 }{ Subentry3 }{ Subentry4 }
```

is

```
\scriptsize Subentry1 \space \Huge Subentry2 ... mainentry1 (Subentry3}{Subentry4}
```

so just the first is in `\scriptsize` and all the later ones are in Huge, the title asks about iteration but there is no iteration here, `\subentry` is only called once.

You can save mainentry1 in the begin code of the environment and use it at the end

```
\def\savedmain{#1}
```

in the begin code and use `\savedmain`in the end code after your subentries. Or (as in earlier questions) you could use the `expl3` environment declarations that let you use `#1` directly in the end code.

i think you are looking for something like this, but I would bnever use such a definition in a docuemnt. Iterating over a `{]` list is completely against latex syntax, where `{}` denotes a mandatory argument and here where you are actually using pairs it just obscures the document.

I would use simple non-iterative definitions and a syntax like

```
\begin{mainentry}{aa}{bb}{cc}

 \subentry{s1}{sss1}
 \subentry{s2}{sss2}
 \subentry{s3}{sss3}

\end{mainentry}
```

Then the code, and the document would be a lot clearer.

However:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%
%
\newenvironment{mainentry}[3]{#1 #2 #3\def\mainentrya{#1}\par}{\mainentrya}
%
\long\def\subentry#1#2{%
\ifx\par#1%
\endgraf\expandafter\end\else
{\scriptsize#1} {\huge#2}\expandafter\subentry
\fi}


%
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{mainentry}{
Mainentry1
}{
Mainentry2
}{
Mainentry3
}

\subentry{
Subentry1
}{
Subentry2
}{
Subentry3
}{
Subentry4
}

\end{mainentry}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. That will solve the second problem. Are you sure there is no iteration? I mean, why do `Subentry3` and `Subentry4` even show up? One can add as many pairs of Subentries, isn't that sort of an iteration? I adapted the code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395594/67761).

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen why would there be any iteration? you only call subentry once (your loop definitions are not used at all) I will add some code.

Comment: I tried to use the code from [this answer, from another OP](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394921/67761).

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen  not with the definition of `\subenry` that you used inside the environment. The definition that you put at the end was never used at all (try deleting it and run your example you will see the same result.

Comment: But, regarding the second question (bullet point in OP) ... your solution can put something right before the end of `\end{mainentry}`, isn't it? But imagine  I have multiple instances of `\subentry{`...`}` after one another, then how do i get `mainentry`'s first argument at the end of each `\subentry{`...`}`?

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen change `\endgraf` in the definition of `\subentry` to `\endgraf\mainentrya\endgraf` and take `\mainentrya` out of the end code of the enviornment.