# latex command for undetermined number of parameters

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, loops, robust-commands

I am trying to use a smart way to typeset some diagrams as these single stranded diagrams.

[image: single stranded diagrams]

But I would like to do two more things, one is to allow n of them to be stacked together as

[image: stacked]

and be able to draw multi-stranded diagrams as

[image: mutltistrand]

Now I already have the command for single-stranded diagrams as

```latex
\newcommand{\Planar}[3]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth'] % if arrow is ture, add these commands
    \draw[color=red] (0,0) rectangle (#1*0.3+0.3,0.7); % draw the outer box according to number of dots
    \newcounter{dotnumber}
    \foreach \dot in {1,...,#1}{ % draw the dots
        \filldraw (0.3*\dot,0) circle [radius=1pt];
        \filldraw (0.3*\dot,0.7) circle [radius=1pt];
    }
    \draw (0.3*#2,0) .. controls +(0,0.2) and +(0,-0.2) .. (0.3*#3,0.7); % draw the line
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

But I am looking for something like this

```latex
\Planar[number_of_dots][number_of_levels][first_strand_starting][first_strand_ending][...][last_strand_starting][last_strand_ending][secondlevelstrands...]
```

That produces the above diagrams with commands as

```latex
\Planar[3][1][1]..., 
\Planar[3][level=2][2][2][2][3]
           |this is the number of levels
\Planar[3][1][2][3][1][3][3]
           |this is the starting dot of the first line
```

I know that this is probably a huge macro and my way of defining the command is hideous, but I would appreciate at least some directions of where to go next.

Comment: Welcome! You can just use pgf keys for that. Then the syntax will be \Planar{ndots=7,nlevels=5,...}, where each key can have an initial/default value.

Comment: related [Macro - Repeat the pattern for any (even) number of arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394779/macro-repeat-the-pattern-for-any-even-number-of-arguments/394820#394820)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is start. Rather than using levels I would define a single `pic` (see section 18.2 of the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) manual), that draws one planar diagram and then you can stack them. The first argument of the `pic` should give the number of dots on the bottom line and the second argument should be a comma separated list of `x`/`y` pairs for the strings. This way you can use:

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (0,0) pic{planar=[3]{1/1}};
     \draw (3,0) pic{planar=[3]{1/2}};
     \draw (6,0) pic{planar=[3]{1/3}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
```

to draw the diagrams

[image]

To stack the diagrams you then put two pics on "top" of each other, so that

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw(0,0) pic{planar=[3]{2/2}};
     \draw(0,0.7) pic{planar=[3]{2/3}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
```

produces:

[image]

Finally, here is an example with multiple strings and four dots: the code

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw(0,0) pic{planar={4}{1/2, 3/1, 3/3}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
```

produces (the non-planar diagram):

[image]

I haven't added a command for the labels, partly because I don't immediately see a good syntax for this and partly because when I draw such diagrams I never label the strings:)

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{pics/planar/.style 2 args = {
    code = {
      \draw[color=red] (0,0) rectangle (#1*0.3+0.3,0.7);
      \foreach \dot in {1,...,#1}{ % draw the dots
          \filldraw (0.3*\dot,0) circle [radius=1pt];
          \filldraw (0.3*\dot,0.7) circle [radius=1pt];
      }
      % draw the lines
      \foreach \x/\y in {#2}
        \draw[->,>=stealth](0.3*\x,0) .. controls +(0,0.2) and +(0,-0.2) .. (0.3*\y,0.7);
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (0,0) pic{planar={3}{1/1}};
     \draw (2,0) pic{planar={3}{1/2}};
     \draw (4,0) pic{planar={3}{1/3}};
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw(0,0) pic{planar={3}{2/2}};
     \draw(0,0.7) pic{planar={3}{2/3}};
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw(0,0) pic{planar={4}{1/2, 3/1, 3/3}};
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As you see I have really just repackaged the code from the OP. Personally, I would replace `0.3` and `0.7` above with `0` and `1` and then rescale the whole environment as this is likely to make your life a little easier in the long run.

**Edit**

Here is a "fancier" `\PlanarDiagram` macro that accepts a comma separated list of coma separated `x`/`y`-pairs to produce products of the corresponding diagrams. For example, the code

```
\PlanarDiagram(5){{1/2}}                  \quad
\PlanarDiagram{{1/2,2/2}, {2/3,3/1}}      \quad
\PlanarDiagram(4){{1/2, 3/1, 3/3}, {1/1, 2/3, 3/3}}
```

produces the output

[image]

Notice that there is an optional argument, which is enclosed in `(...)`, that gives the number of dots. This another optional argument that you can use to configure the underlying `tikzpicture1` environment and the `pic`. So, for example,

```
\PlanarDiagram[scale=0.5, draw=blue](4){{1/2, 3/1, 3/3}, {1/1, 2/3, 3/3}}
```

produces:

[image]

Here is the updated code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{pics/planar/.style 2 args = {
    code = {
      \draw[color=red] (0,0) rectangle (#1*0.3+0.3,0.7);
      \foreach \dot in {1,...,#1}{ % draw the dots
          \filldraw (0.3*\dot,0) circle [radius=1pt];
          \filldraw (0.3*\dot,0.7) circle [radius=1pt];
      }
      % draw the lines
      \foreach \x/\y in #2
        \draw[->,>=stealth](0.3*\x,0) .. controls +(0,0.2) and +(0,-0.2) .. (0.3*\y,0.7);
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\PlanarDiagram{ O{} D(){3} m }{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
     \foreach \diag [count=\c] in {#3} {
       \draw(0,\c*0.7) pic[#1]{planar={#2}{\diag}};
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

   \PlanarDiagram(5){{1/2}}                  \quad
   \PlanarDiagram{{1/2,2/2}, {2/3,3/1}}      \quad
   \PlanarDiagram(4){{1/2, 3/1, 3/3}, {1/1, 2/3, 3/3}}

   \PlanarDiagram[scale=0.7, draw=blue](4){{1/2, 3/1, 3/3}, {1/1, 2/3, 3/3}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow that's super great work! It's kind of overwhelming using the tikz library in the beginning but your answer is a great example for me to work on! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

As an exercise, I took a crack at this with `metapost`.  The syntax is:

```
planar(n,m)("connections")
```

where `n` is the number of points per level, `m` is the number of levels, and `connections` is a list of the form

```
level 1 arrows | level 2 arrows | level 3 arrows |...
```

where the arrows within each level are given as a comma separated list of ordered pairs.  For example

```
planar(3,1)("(1,1),(2,3),(3,2)");
```

produces

[image]

and

```
planar(3,2)("(1,1),(2,3),(3,2)|(3,1),(1,3),(2,2)");
```

produces

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibforcehmode
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
ux:=1cm; % horizontal scale
uy:=2cm; % vertical scale
ds:=.15*ux; % dot size

def planar(expr pts,levels)(text connections)=
    clearxy; save k,l,n;
    x=(pts+1)*ux; y=levels*uy; % max x, max y
    for i=0 upto levels:
        draw (origin--(x,0)) shifted (0,i*uy) withcolor red; % draw horizontal bars
        for j=1 upto pts: drawdot (j*ux,i*uy) withpen pencircle scaled ds; endfor; % draw dots
    endfor;
    draw origin--(0,y) withcolor red; % draw left vertical bar
    draw (x,0)--(x,y) withcolor red; % draw right vertical bar
    l=length(connections); n=k=0;
    for i=0 upto l:
        if (substring(i,i+1) of connections="|") or (i=l): % find separators
            for p=scantokens(substring(k,i) of connections): % iterate through list up to separator
                drawarrow ((xpart p)*ux,n*uy){up}..{up}((ypart p)*ux,(n+1)*uy) 
                          cutafter fullcircle scaled (ds+1) shifted ((ypart p)*ux,(n+1)*uy);
            endfor;
        k:=i+1; % pickup after separator
        n:=n+1; % increase level
        fi;
    endfor;
enddef;

beginfig(0);
    planar(3,2)("(1,1),(2,3),(3,2)|(3,1),(1,3),(2,2)");
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow this website never stops surprising me! This is a very elegant implementation as well! Thanks!