# Aligning tikzpictures with equations and user-defined commands

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, vertical-alignment

I am trying to aligned the following diagrams to the center.

[image: fail]

Somehow I just cannot do it. I tried `scope`, `baseline` and `\vbox` and even wrapping with `\begin{matrix}\end{matrix}`. All of them give the same result as above.

Here is the code I used

```latex
\begin{equation}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[scale=0.6] at (0.3,-0.2) {5};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (0.6,-0.2) {3};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (0.9,-0.2) {4};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (1.2,-0.2) {1};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (1.5,-0.2) {2};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (0.3,0.9) {1};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (0.6,0.9) {2};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (0.9,0.9) {3};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (1.2,0.9) {4};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (1.5,0.9) {5};
        \PlanarDiagram(5){{1/3,2/4,3/1,4/2,5/5}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    =1
    \end{equation}
```

with the defined command from [latex command for undetermined number of parameters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530827/latex-command-for-undetermined-number-of-parameters/)

```latex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{braids,backgrounds,arrows.meta,positioning,fit}
\tikzset{pics/planar/.style 2 args = {
        code = {
            \draw[color=red] (0,0) rectangle (#1*0.3+0.3,0.7);
            \foreach \dot in {1,...,#1}{ % draw the dots
                \filldraw (0.3*\dot,0) circle [radius=1pt];
                \filldraw (0.3*\dot,0.7) circle [radius=1pt];
            }
            % draw the lines
            \foreach \x/\y in #2
            \draw[->,>=stealth](0.3*\x,0) .. controls +(0,0.2) and +(0,-0.2) .. (0.3*\y,0.7);
        }
    }
}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\PlanarDiagram{ O{} D(){3} m }{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
    \foreach \diag [count=\c] in {#3} {
        \draw(0,\c*0.7) pic[#1]{planar={#2}{\diag}};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Am I missing something or should I change the defined command?

Comment: Your document nests `tikzpicture`s. This is to be absolutely avoided, and is (one of) the reason(s) for your problems. In addition, `\MathAxis` is undefined in your fragments.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for the hint for \MacthAxis, I tried that before but it did not work and I forgot to remove it. As for the nesting tikzpictures, that's why I tried the scope. Sadly it did not work as well. Also I need to be able to use the \PlanarDidagram separately so I think this is the best I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, there are three important rules:

1. Never nest `tikzpicture`s!
2. Never!
3. If you load `pgf`, you have one of the best means for optional arguments in the LaTeX world. (If you do not load `pgf`, of course `xparse` is great for optional arguments.)

You can build in everything into one `pic` with just keys taking care of all the variations. If you later decide to add some feature, add a key. The old syntax will still work. I just added a key `show labels` to (some variation) of your `pic`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifPlanarDiagamShowLabels
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\tikzset{pics/planar diagram/.style={code={
            \tikzset{planar diagram/.cd,#1}%
            \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/planar diagram/##1}}%
            \draw[/tikz/planar diagram/frame] ({-(\pv{n}+1)*\pv{x}/2},-\pv{y}/2) rectangle 
                ({(\pv{n}+1))*\pv{x}/2},\pv{y}/2);
            \ifPlanarDiagamShowLabels
              \path foreach \XX in {1,...,\pv{n}}
              {({-(\pv{n}+1)*\pv{x}/2+\XX*\pv{x}},-\pv{y}/2)
                   node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$\XX$] (-b-\XX){}
               ({-(\pv{n}+1)*\pv{x}/2+\XX*\pv{x}},\pv{y}/2)
                   node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above:$\XX$] (-t-\XX){}};
            \else
              \path foreach \XX in {1,...,\pv{n}}
              {({-(\pv{n}+1)*\pv{x}/2+\XX*\pv{x}},-\pv{y}/2)
                   node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] (-b-\XX){}
               ({-(\pv{n}+1)*\pv{x}/2+\XX*\pv{x}},\pv{y}/2)
                   node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] (-t-\XX){}};
            \fi
            \edef\localconnections{\pv{connections}}
            \foreach \XX/\YY in \localconnections{%
            \draw[-{Stealth[bend]}] (-b-\XX) to[out=90,in=-90] (-t-\YY);
            }
    }},planar diagram/.cd,n/.initial=5,x/.initial=0.3,y/.initial=0.7,
    show labels/.is if=PlanarDiagamShowLabels,frame/.style={},
    connections/.initial={1/1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(X.base)}]
   \path node(X){\phantom{X}} 
   pic[nodes={scale=0.6},every circle node/.append style={scale=5/3}]
   {planar diagram={n=5,% number of nodes
        show labels,% show numbers
        frame/.style={draw=red},% red box
        connections={1/3,2/4,3/1,4/2,5/5}% which circles get connected
        }};      
  \end{tikzpicture}
    =1
\end{equation}


\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[row sep=-3pt]{\pic{planar diagram={n=3,connections={3/1}}};\\
\pic{planar diagram={n=3,connections={2/3}}};\\
\pic{planar diagram={n=3,connections={2/2}}};\\
};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\]  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I am wondering if this allows stacking as in [latex command for undetermined number of parameters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530827/latex-command-for-undetermined-number-of-parameters/)? I am still trying to read your code, and I am not sure if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @waterliu Sure, it does. Just set `show labels` to false and stack them. The perhaps most convenient way to stack them is to put them in a `\matrix`.

Comment: I tried this and it seems not to be happy with it```\begin{equation}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(X.base)}]
   \path node(X){\phantom{X}} 
   pic[nodes={scale=0.6}]{planar diagram={n=5,connections={{1/3,3/1,4/2},{5/5}}}};      
  \end{tikzpicture}
    =1
    \end{equation}```

Comment: @waterliu Did you run my above code as is?

Comment: Oh I see your update. I will use the matrix then. Before I just added the commands after your example and got some weird results.

Comment: @waterliu You need the full preamble `\newif\ifPlanarDiagamShowLabels
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\tikzset{pics/planar diagram/.style={code={ ... }}`, otherwise it won't work. The `\newif` is needed for the `show labels` switch, and I like bent arrows better. As I said, this setting is upgradable without losing downward compatibility. That is, if you want to add further switches and/or features, you can do so without making your older codes dysfunctional.

Comment: Got it! Your solution seems to be very latex-y, and it does work well! I will stick with my own tiny walk-around for now lol.

Answer (score 0):

I got another walk-around thanks to Schrödinger's cat. Once I remove the outer layer I am able to use the original code.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{braids,backgrounds,arrows.meta,fit}
\tikzset{pics/planar/.style 2 args = {
        code = {
            \draw[color=red] (0,0) rectangle (#1*0.3+0.3,0.7);
            \foreach \dot in {1,...,#1}{ % draw the dots
                \filldraw (0.3*\dot,0) circle [radius=1pt];
                \filldraw (0.3*\dot,0.7) circle [radius=1pt];
            }
            % draw the lines
            \foreach \x/\y in #2
            \draw[->,>=stealth](0.3*\x,0) .. controls +(0,0.2) and +(0,-0.2) .. (0.3*\y,0.7);
        }
    }
}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\PlanarDiagram{ O{} D(){3} m }{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
    \foreach \diag [count=\c] in {#3} {
        \draw (0,\c*0.7) pic[#1]{planar={#2}{\diag}};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand\planarDiagram{ O{} D(){3} m }{%
    \foreach \diag [count=\c] in {#3} {
        \draw (0,\c*0.7) pic[#1]{planar={#2}{\diag}};
    }
}


\begin{document}
        \begin{equation} 
        \begin{matrix}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-0.7)}]
        \planarDiagram(5){{1/3,2/4,3/1,4/2,5/5}};
        \end{scope}
        \node[scale=0.6] at (0.3,-0.2) {3};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (0.6,-0.2) {4};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (0.9,-0.2) {1};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (1.2,-0.2) {2};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (1.5,-0.2) {5};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (0.3,0.9) {5};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (0.6,0.9) {1};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (0.9,0.9) {2};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (1.2,0.9) {3};
        \node[scale=0.6] at (1.5,0.9) {4};

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{matrix}=1
        \end{equation}
\end{document}
```